# How to insert list item into listview without modifying the underlying data set?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView that is populated by an ArrayAdapter, and I need to insert an advertisement after every Nth legitimate list item.  The easiest way I can think of to do this would be to modify the array that defines the adapter's data set directly (or indirectly, via ArrayAdapter::add/insert) as follows:

```
/**
 * Injects ad entries into the station list after every N legit entries
 * 
 * @param adapter the arrayadapter that will generate the views representing our legit and ad list items
 */
private void injectAdEntries(MyArrayAdapter adapter){
    int legitItemCount = adapter.getCount();
    int adStride = 4;
    if(legitItemCount >= adStride) {
        //adstride-1 to account for the 0 index
        for (int legitItemIndex = adStride-1; legitItemIndex < legitItemCount; legitItemIndex += adStride) {
            //create clone of last legit entry, to use as context
            // data for the ad, and mark it 'illegitimate' (ad)
            LegitObject totallyLegit = new LegitObject(adapter.getItem(legitItemIndex));
            totallyLegit.setLegit(false);
            adapter.insert(totallyLegit,legitItemIndex+1);

        }
    }
}
```

After the injection, MyArrayAdapter's getView override can detect the false legit value and handle advertisement entries differently from legitimate entries.

The trouble is that I don't want to pollute the legitimate data array.   Ideally, I would insert these advertisement list items without modifying the underlying data set in any way.  Is there a way to make an adapter produce views that aren't reflected in its data set?

**Edit**

I also need all the items in the legitimate data set to be displayed in the ListView; the ad list items need to appear 'in addition to' rather than 'instead of' legitimate list items.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are using a recyclerView as a list. So, to have heterogenous layouts (i.e.: YOUR ACTUAL ITEM LAYOUT + AD LAYOUT) you should follow these steps:

1. Override `getItemView` like

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       // insert an Ad every multiple of 5
       if (position % 5 == 0) {
           return AD_POSITION;
       }
       return NORMAL_POSITION;
   }
   ```
2. Next, you need to override the `onCreateViewHolder` method to tell the `RecyclerView.Adapter` about which `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` object to create based on the `viewType` returned.

   ```
   @Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
       RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

       switch (viewType) {
           case AD_POSITION:
               View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_ad, viewGroup, false);
               viewHolder = new AdViewHolder(v1);
               break;
           default:
               // NORMAL_POSITION
               View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
               viewHolder = new NormalViewHolder(v);
               break;
       }
       return viewHolder;
   }
   ```

For more details you can check this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) out.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but my current implementation is based on ListView + ArrayAdapter, and ideally I'd like to find a solution that works within that framework (if possible).  Also, I'm not sure I want to commit to such a new framework class (RecyclerView was added in API level 22) now that the support lib minimum API level seems to have crept up to a floor of 9 [https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions] -- I need to support back to 16 for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach still require modifying the underlying data set?  RecyclerView's adapter and layout positions have to derive from the data set given to the RecyclerView.Adapter (I think), so while you could display heterogeneous data with the benefit of an item view type determined by position, said data would still have to come from a single source.  In the example above, wouldn't the normal entries at positions that are multiples of 5 effectively be dropped in favor of an ad?  Anyway, my goal is to keep the normal list item entries' data separate from ads as much as possible.

Comment: For your **first comment**, I think you will just gain more in performance (specially) and don't loose anything by moving to RecyclerView, and if you support back to API 9, you are supporting almost more than 99% of android phones. For your **second comment** I don't really know much about your data (that you are passing to the Adapter) but I'm sure you don't have to do a lot of tweaks to make it work.